# Firebase "update" is adding a child node that I do not want it to add

Tags: php, string, rss, firebase

I'm parsing an RSS feed and trying to update my firebase based on the rss data.
If I update the title using a hardcoded string, for example 'foo', it works fine.

```
   $sacarray = array('title' => 'foo');
   $response = $fb->update('/sac/past1', $sacarray);
```

Results in:

> sac => past1 => title:foo

But if I update via my variable, it is adding an inadvertent extra node below 'title'.

```
    $items = $xml->channel->item;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++)
    {     
        $sacarray = array('title' => $items[$i]->title);
        $response = $fb->update('/sac/past1', $sacarray);    
    }
```

So that it looks in my firebase like:

> sac => past1 => title => 0:foo

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have some very similar code in a different php file which is working fine, so I can't figure out what I am doing differently.  It seems as though it is interpreting $items[$i]->title incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. Probably not the correct solution, but I found something that works.

If I tried to just place the rss item title into a new variable, I still had the same issue:

```
$title = $items[$i]->title;
$sacarray = array('title' => $title);
```

But if append something to the title (an empty character) - then it decides to treat it as a string and everything works as I would expect.

```
$title = $items[$i]->title.'';
$sacarray = array('title' => $title);
```

Not sure if this if this is something with php string handling that I am just not aware of because of the fact that I don't do a lot php coding. Or if this is being caused by the SimpleXmlElement class that I using to parse the rss feed.

UPDATE: Ok, I just figured out that casting to a string also works. I still dont understand why it needs casted though.

Comment: It's probably because they're objects, hence the need to cast as string

Comment: Actually casting as string is what you should do instead of adding a blank nothing